# Does not rendering index with default view in ember-1.6.1

Tags: templates, view, ember.js, handlebars.js

As-salamu-wa-alicum

Every body,

I have a index.html with

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
        <div id="tabcontent" class="post" contenteditable="true">
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
    </script>
```

applicationView.js with

```
App.applicationView = Ember.View.extend({
template:Ember.Handlebars.compile('welcomeTemplate.hbs')
,templateName:'application'
});
```

In js/templates/welcomeTemplate.hbs is

```
 <div><p>Welcome</p></div>
```

In app.js I have

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ });
```

In console log I am getting

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.6.1
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
DEBUG: -------------------------------
generated -> route:application Object { fullName="route:application"}
generated -> route:index Object { fullName="route:index"}
generated -> controller:application Object { fullName="controller:application"}
Rendering application with default view <(subclass of Ember.View):ember211> Object {
     fullName ="view:application"}
generated -> controller:index Object { fullName="controller:index"}
**Could not find "index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {
     fullName="template:index"}**
log:
Transitioned into 'index'
```

Please tell me what is going on here and why am I not see the "Welcome" in browser at /index.html? How will I see "Welcome" in browser at /index.html?

Thank you very much

With best regards
Nadvi.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to have both a template and a templateName.  Additionally application should be uppercase.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  template:Ember.Handlebars.compile('Hello {{name}}<br/>Name: {{input value=name}}')
});
```

Ember doesn't load files for you, so stating a hbs name won't do anything, it'll just think of it as a plain string you wanted to show in the page.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/joyiqute/1/edit

Comment: Would you like to tell me how could I load and compile .hbs? I changed  the application  to uppercase and remove the templatename  and saw that the compiled content ware added at the last of the body not in the place of the script.